# How to use the python subprocess to get the latest commit id from master(git repo)

Tags: python, git

I am unable to get the latest commit id from the master using the python subprocess task . Please note the details below.

Script details:

```
Release_Commit_result= subprocess.check_output("git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:","%H")
```

when I ran the script, I am getting following out put as,

OUtput:

```
Release_Commit_result= subprocess.check_output("git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:","%H")

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
```

TypeError:

> **init**() got multiple values for `enter code here`keyword argument 'stdout'

This git command alone actually gives the out put when it ran from the git bash.

Comment: Could you please format your question better, insert some code and give us a traceback.

Comment: I think something is missing in your description, where it is written "enter your code here". Moreover could you post a full traceback?

Comment: Hi @Fabrizio, I modified the question. I

Comment: Hi @Fabrizio, Thank you. I modified the question. And this was the part of Continues integration where I need to get the latest commit id from the master once it pulled. I missed to add the directory path where the cloning and pull is done in the entire process. so the below command worked for me.
latest_commit = subprocess.check_output(["git", "-C", <GIT_DIR>, "log","--format=%H", master])
this will give all commit and below step would retrieve only the latest one until the next pull hepend.
print(latest_commit[0:40] )

Answer (score 2):

Execute the command giving the arguments in an array or in a single string. Like this:

```
subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-1", "--pretty-format:%H"])
```

Please see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html as reference.

**UPDATE**
Edited command according to phd's suggestion, in the comments.

Comment: `"%H"` also must be combined: `"--pretty-format:%H"`.